# May a trained hunting animal kill the prey or must it only bring the prey alive?

Tags: halal-haram, meat, hunting

I am not a Moslem but I saw that the Quran permits using trained animals to catch animals for humans to eat. [Quran[5:4]](http://quran.com/5/4)

May the trained animal kill the prey or must it only bring the prey alive to the Moslem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bismillah,

> May the trained animal kill the prey or must it only bring the prey
>   alive to the Moslem?

The trained animal may do either one; kill the prey or bring it alive, as long as it doesn't eat from it.

There is a hadith in [Sahih Muslim](http://hadithcollection.com/sahihmuslim/149-Sahih%20Muslim%20Book%2021.%20Games%20and%20Animals%20Which%20May%20be%20Slaughtered%20/13154-sahih-muslim-book-021-hadith-number-4733.html) that says:

> 'Adi b. Hatim reported: I asked Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon
>   him) saying: We are a people who hunt with these (trained) dogs, then
>   (what should we do)? Thereupon he (the Holy Prophet) said: **When you
>   set of your trained dogs having recited the name of Allah, then eat
>   what these (hounds) have caught for you, even if it (the game) is
>   killed, provided (the hunting dog) has not eaten (any part of the
>   game).** If it has eaten (the game), then you don't eat it as I fear
>   that it might have caught for its own self. And do not eat in case
>   other dogs have joined your trained dogs.

**Edit: the verse you are talking about is not #5, it is #4 in Chapter 5 (Al-Ma'idah).**

Comment: Does this still apply if e.g. The trained animal brings down a cow that would normally require slaughter with a knife?